# Reverse clip with ogr2ogr

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, ogr2ogr, google-fusion-tables

I'm fairly new to GIS, working on a project where I overlay counties on google maps, and overlay cities on top. I'm using fusion tables, and running into Z-index issues. To get around this I'm hoping to take the county tiger gis shape files and "adjust" the lines to only draw areas where there are no "places" from tiger gis. It seems like I'm looking for a reverse clipping, any hints on how to accomplish this with ogr2ogr?

A copy of the script I'm using to get to this point can be found at: https://github.com/TinyHouse/shape_to_sql/blob/master/shape_to_sql